# Finding the joint density for the ratio of gamma distributions

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, density-function, gamma-distribution

Let $S_n$ be a random variable with the PDF of the gamma distribution when $\lambda = 1$:
$$
f_{S_n}(s_n) = \frac{x^{n-1}}{\Gamma(n)}e^{-s_n}.
$$
My goal is to find the joint distribution of the random variable $\frac{S_i}{S_n}$ where $i < n$. My thought is that I could do this using Bayes theorem:

$$
f_{S_n}(S_n|S_i) = \frac{f_{S_iS_n}(s_i,s_n)}{f_{S_i}(s_i)}.
$$
But I am not exactly sure what $f_{S_n}(S_n|S_i)$ would be. I know that
$$
f_{S_n}(s_n) = f_{S_i}(s_i)\cdot \frac{x^{n-i}}{\Gamma(n)/\Gamma(i)}e^{-s_n+s_i}.
$$
Any suggestions would be much appriciated.

Comment: Bayes' Theorem says:- $$f_{\lower{0.5ex}{S_n\mid S_i}}(s_n\mid s_i)=\dfrac{f_{\lower{0.5ex}{S_i,S_n}}(s_i,s_n)}{f_{\lower{0.5ex}{S_i}}(s_i)}$$

Comment: ooh, so this is not even close to the right approach

Comment: There should be no $x$ in the expression. It is:- $$f_{S_n}(s_n) =\dfrac{{s_n}^{n-1}\mathrm e^{-s_n}}{\Gamma(j)}\mathbf 1_{0<s_n}$$

Answer (score 2):

> $$f_{S_n}(S_n|S_i) = \frac{f_{S_iS_n}(s_i,s_n)}{f_{S_i}(s_i)}.$$

Bayes' Theorem says:- $$f_{S_n\mid S_i}(s_n\mid s_i)=\dfrac{f_{S_i,S_n}(s_i,s_n)}{f_{S_i}(s_i)}$$

However, you seek the **[ratio distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_distribution)** $$\begin{align}f_{S_i/S_n}(r)=\mathbf 1_{0<r}\,\int_0^\infty s\,f_{S_i,S_n}(rs,s)\,\mathrm d s \end{align}$$

Yet, to find *that*, you do still need to identify *how*, *if* they are not independent, these gamma distributed random variables are related?  Ie what is their joint distribution?

---

For instance, if $(X_k)$ is a sequence of independent and identically *exponential* distributed random variables (with rate parameter $1$), then their sum is Gamma distributed.$$\sum_{k=1}^j X_k\sim \mathcal{Gamma}(j, 1)$$

If this is your case, then you may relate $S_i$ and $S_n$, since $S_i$ and $S_n{-}S_i$ are independent.$$\begin{align}f_{S_i,S_n}(t,s)&=f_{S_i}(t)~f_{S_n-S_i}(s-t)\\[1ex]&=\dfrac{{t}^{i-1}\mathrm e^{-t}}{\Gamma(i)}\cdot\dfrac{(s-t)^{n-i-1}\mathrm e^{-(s-t)}}{\Gamma(n-i)}\\[1ex]&=\dfrac{{t}^{i-1}(s-t)^{n-i-1}\mathrm e^{-s}}{\Gamma(i)\Gamma(n-i)}  \end{align}$$

Comment: Wait, I didnt know that $S_n$ and $S_i$ are independent, how could they? $S_i$ is inside of $S_n$ if $i<n$?

Comment: I realize I may not have said that in my question $(X_k)$ is a sequence of independent exponential distribution, and $S_n= \sum_{k=1}^j X_k$, does this still mean they are independent?

Comment: No but $\sum_{k=0}^i X_k$ and $\sum_{k=i+1}^n X_k$ are independent.  That is $S_i$ and $S_n-S_i$.